# i want to add images in $_Files directly from my code in php

Tags: php

i am writing code in php so that rather than posting images from form i want to add images in $_files direct from my code

Comment: congratulations! Did you have a question or a problem you're trying to solve? Maybe some code that could help us understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: as Bob is pointing out, to help with problems we need to know what you're trying to do (which you've got), how you're trying to do it and what is actually happening, including any error messages. For more on writing questions on SO and elsewhere, read ["Writing the perfect question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), as well as the FAQs (available from that link on the top of the page).

Comment: An why would you need to do that after all? (That is, adding to $_FILES, not asking a question)

Answer (score 2):

`$_FILES` is just an array like any other, except that when the script starts, it's pre-populated with information regarding any file uploads.

This array is writable, and you can use it to store any information you like. So to add a new element to the array, just add it as you would any other.

Doing so will have no other side-effects however. You'll just have another element in the array. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

As tylerl said, `$_FILES` is an array like any other. Just have two things in mind:

- There is a difference how the $_FILES array looks for files that were submitted by a) inputs with different names and b) inputs with "array" names like `file[]`.
- The `is_uploaded_file()` and `move_uploaded_file()` function **will not work**!